# kinect installation with ROS Kinetic Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed openNi, NITE and PrimeSense for Kinect Sensor.

When I enter `roslaunch openni_launch openni_launch`

it is not funding the package.

```
[openni_launch] is neither a launch file in package [openni_launch] nor is [openni_launch] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I am a beginner. Guide me in this regard.

Thanks

PS: I also followed #q207642. but didn't succeed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266143/kinect-installation-with-ros-kinetic-ubuntu-16.04/) by [fmnoori](https://answers.ros.org/users/31124/fmnoori/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a typo, this is correct:

> roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

the last dot in your command was a _

---

Originally posted by [agutenkunst](https://answers.ros.org/users/30729/agutenkunst/) with karma: 90 on 2017-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fmnoori](https://answers.ros.org/users/31124/fmnoori/) on 2017-07-12**:
oh thank you.
It was the mistake in the tutorial. Working now . thanks :)

**Comment by [fmnoori](https://answers.ros.org/users/31124/fmnoori/) on 2017-07-12**:
I was watching the things on Rviz using

rosrun rviz rviz

I can see my images (rgb + depth). I want to see depth cloud but there is an error in my global status

Global status  error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist.

Can you help me how to fix it now.